Where is the negative charge localized in tetrazolate ion?
I am seeing images of tetrazolate ion where the negative charge is placed at different locations:

On the nitrogen atom



Inside the tetrazole ring

 or 

On the carbon atom


Is there any electronic charge distribution calculation done on this anion to confirm where is the negative charge situated? Is resonance playing a part?

Has the methylation of it been reported?

Do you have a link to a reported structure? Googling tetrazolate and Sodium Azidotetrazole give different structures from the above.

OK, I found a structure in the Cambridge Structural Database for the tetramethyl ammonium salt

Did a quick calculation on the tetramethyl ammonium salt. Only looked at the Mulliken charges, so take it with a pinch of salt, but they suggest that 2 is the best description, and that 3 is just plain incorrect (the carbon comes out as nett positive) but that flat delocalisation around the whole ring is a slight simplification, and there is some concentration of the electronic charge onto the nitrogens next to the carbons.  Late now. Will write it up tomorrow.

Umm, it's fully delocalised, so I don't see a problem? It's not actual charge, which could indeed be slightly positive on C.

I think naming of the product of your first scheme is incorrect. It should be sodium 5,5’-azotetrazolate.

According to my search, 5-amino-tetrazole can exist in two tautomers:  5-amino-1H-tetrazole and 5-amino-2H-tetrazole. It never be in 5-amino-5H-tetrazole form because it'd loose its aromaticity. Same argument is true for  sodium 5,5’-azotetrazolate.

(Final update at end - TLDR: I did a Bader aka Atoms in Molecules analysis)
I did a quick run with CRYSTAL23, a local basis set code that concentrates on periodic structures rather than isolated molecules (disclaimer: I am an author of CRYSTAL) on a structure for the tetramethylammonium salt found on the Cambridge Structural Database. I have put CIF file, the input for the run, and the output on bitbucket in a git repository
Firstly note this is about the quickest calculation I can do. Should time, effort and willingness permit I want to check the computational parameters, where I have essentially just used the defaults, the basis set, and especially I would want to do a geometry optimization rather than just an SCF at the experimental geometry. However I would hope the single point SCF will get the essence.
The CIF reports a P-1 structure. In the cell the "left" hand side of the ion is related to the right by an inversion. CRYSTAL pairs the atoms off such that the odd numbered atom N is related by the inversion to the even numbered atom N+1. Due to the symmetry we only need look at the odd numbered atoms. Here is the numbering (but I need to check I have 5<->7 and 9<->11 the right way around, but it doesn't really change the discussion if I haven't)

Atom number 1 is the nitrogen in the tetramethylammonium counter anion.
For the calculation I have used a triple zeta POB basis set, and uses the B3LYP DFT functional. The shrinking factor for the Monkhorst k-point net is 2, resulting in 8 k points - if I come back to this I would want to investigate increasing that to check convergence.
Here are the electronic Mulliken charges as reported by CRYSTAL for the relevant atoms. To get the formal charge on the "atom" you have to subtract that from the nuclear charge:
     ALPHA+BETA ELECTRONS
 MULLIKEN POPULATION ANALYSIS - NO. OF ELECTRONS  168.000000

  ATOM    Z CHARGE  A.O. POPULATION

   3 N    7  7.314  0.819  1.153  0.738  0.748  0.414  0.510  0.586  0.480
                    0.512  0.669  0.156  0.159  0.232  0.038  0.022  0.035
                    0.023  0.020
   5 N    7  7.436  0.819  1.153  0.734  0.754  0.481  0.555  0.480  0.548
                    0.595  0.511  0.245  0.268  0.159  0.030  0.031  0.043
                    0.016  0.015
   7 N    7  7.380  0.819  1.153  0.737  0.733  0.471  0.536  0.510  0.540
                    0.578  0.528  0.212  0.207  0.232  0.035  0.023  0.030
                    0.022  0.015
   9 N    7  7.156  0.819  1.152  0.749  0.708  0.483  0.541  0.455  0.542
                    0.558  0.474  0.194  0.208  0.139  0.037  0.029  0.034
                    0.016  0.015
  11 N    7  7.193  0.819  1.152  0.750  0.726  0.441  0.437  0.597  0.510
                    0.470  0.593  0.166  0.150  0.249  0.021  0.024  0.041
                    0.027  0.021
  13 C    6  5.319  0.854  1.119  0.735  0.296  0.404  0.443  0.449  0.101
                    0.093  0.077  0.339  0.183  0.069  0.048  0.025  0.044
                    0.020  0.020

It can be seen that using the Mulliken charges the carbon has a charge of about +0.7e, while all the nitrogens are negatively charged, with a small concentration of the charge on atoms 5, 7, and 3. The total charge on this half of the ion is ~-0.8e. Mulliken charges have many drawbacks, so take this with a pinch of a salt, but this suggests that of the descriptions mentioned in the question number 2 is most consistent with these results.

Update
I let the geometry optimization run through the day, also increasing the shrinking factor to 4 for better k point sampling, and changing the DFT function to B3LYP-D3 to include semi-empirical corrections for non-bonded interactions.The GitHub repository has had the new files added to it.
In practice the optimization made only a very small difference to the structure. For instance the initial lattice parameters are
 LATTICE PARAMETERS  (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - PRIMITIVE CELL
       A          B          C        ALPHA      BETA     GAMMA        VOLUME
    5.65440    8.19370    9.22620    99.80700  92.70200  99.24400    414.516015

while the final one for the optimized structure are
 LATTICE PARAMETERS (ANGSTROMS AND DEGREES) - BOHR = 0.5291772083 ANGSTROM
 PRIMITIVE CELL - CENTRING CODE 1/0 VOLUME=   389.474865 - DENSITY  1.331 g/cm^3
         A              B              C           ALPHA      BETA       GAMMA 
     5.55974580     7.98775603     9.08121415    99.559810  92.668200 100.741178

and this is reflected by only a small change in the Mulliken charges:
   3 N    7  7.302  0.819  1.153  0.736  0.749  0.423  0.491  0.593  0.489
                    0.513  0.667  0.153  0.152  0.227  0.038  0.023  0.033
                    0.024  0.019
   5 N    7  7.437  0.819  1.153  0.736  0.779  0.484  0.541  0.475  0.552
                    0.590  0.519  0.240  0.254  0.160  0.030  0.032  0.041
                    0.017  0.015
   7 N    7  7.374  0.819  1.153  0.738  0.756  0.473  0.523  0.508  0.546
                    0.575  0.536  0.205  0.201  0.216  0.036  0.023  0.029
                    0.023  0.015
   9 N    7  7.139  0.820  1.152  0.752  0.749  0.484  0.529  0.446  0.547
                    0.561  0.471  0.188  0.187  0.123  0.036  0.030  0.035
                    0.016  0.014
  11 N    7  7.186  0.820  1.152  0.753  0.766  0.435  0.429  0.589  0.509
                    0.475  0.591  0.160  0.143  0.230  0.020  0.026  0.040
                    0.027  0.020
  13 C    6  5.309  0.854  1.119  0.735  0.282  0.405  0.433  0.449  0.099
                    0.093  0.076  0.332  0.205  0.070  0.049  0.026  0.042
                    0.018  0.020

These are essentially the same as before.

Final Update
Due to the use the deficiencies of the Mulliken Population analysis I have now also performed a Bader aka Atoms In Molecules population analysis, this being considered the "gold standard" for this kind of thing, see e.g. Which one, Mulliken charge distribution and NBO, is more reliable?.
Here are the results for the atoms of interest, comparing the Mulliken and Bader results:

It can be seen that the Bader results roughly follow the Mulliken ones, with in general the Bader results showing a greater degree of charge separation than the Mulliken ones. Thus the conclusion above does not change, model 2 with the charge delocalised around the ring and onto the pendant nitrogen is the one most consistent with these results.

I generally like the approach, but Mulliken Population analysis wouldn't be my first choice. Maybe you have time to spare and do a different one. The worst thing about it is that they "get worse" with larger basis sets. So when you'd expect them to converge by increasing the level of theory, they don't. This Q&A might be helpful: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15569/4945 I don't know how your program interfaces to others, but Multiwfn has a couple of pop. analyses you could try.

@Martin-マーチン Indeed, Mulliken is simply the quickest thing I could think of. And to be honest I'm more a programmer than a practitioner nowadays so I'm not always aware of the best ways to approach solving the scientific problem; any suggestions are gratefully accepted
