Why is tetrazole acidic?
Why is tetrazole acidic? It is already aromatic, so why would the negative charge of its conjugate base be more stable and how? Does it really delocalize in the pi orbitals?

Yup, it's fully delocalised. I made a big edit there, check if it's OK with you.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/183368/where-is-the-negative-charge-localized-in-tetrazolate-ion

thank you, didn´t come up on my search. Why is triazole  neutral? so the electron  goes from sp3 orbital into PI orbital then back to a sp3?

Which tetrazole  you are talking about, $1H$-, $2H$-, or $5H$-?

talking about 1H and 2H

No electron is going  "from sp3 orbital into PI orbital then back". If you have two lone pairs on N then it's not like one of them is anionic and the other not. Delocalisation of one of them means spreading of charge.

spread over what orbitals?

The acidity $(\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a})$ of tetrazoles are comparable with that of carboxylic acids, which is given as 4.9 (Ref.1). Thus, according to Wikipedia:

Tetrazoles can act as bioisosteres for carboxylate groups because they have similar $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ and are deprotonated at physiological $\mathrm{pH}$.

When you look at tetrazoles, three isomers of the parent tetrazole exist, differing in the position of the double bonds: $1H$-, $2H$-, and $5H$-tetrazole:

According to the Ref. 2, all three forms are in tautomerism. If you look carefully, the $5H$-tetrazole is closely resemblance to 1'3-cyclopentadiene. Thus, it is safe to assume that tetrazole is fairly acidic. It is clear that when consider the electronic structure and geometry of $1H$- and $2H$-tetrazoles and its conjugate base, which is the driving force for this acidity (Ref. 2):

Above image shows the charges on the ring atoms of the most stable forms of parent tetrazole (unsubstituted) calculated at B3LYP/6-31G* level. The last two figures are the protonated forms of them, which are also stable, and hence, tetrazole can act as base as well. These data demonstrate that the electronic structure of different tetrazole forms is essentially dissimilar. However, the tetrazolate anion (conjugate base of both $1H$- and $2H$-tetrazoles) is a highly symmetric structure with the negative charge well delocalized throughout the ring, making it the better stabilized form among all other forms.
It is worth noting that in the neutral molecules ($1H$- and $2H$-tetrazoles), the highest negative charge is located on the nitrogen in position 4 ($-0.299$ and $-0.277$, respectively), which is the atom will most effectively interact with incoming electrophiles such as protons. the nitrogen in position 1 in the $2H$-tetrazole is also considerably negatively charged ($-0.254$) and can react with electrophiles (see the structures of two protonated forms).
Note: The above calculations are reliable. Compare the calculated bond lengths and experimental values of them listed in Ref. 2:
$$
\begin{array}{|cccc|}
\hline
\text{Compound} & \ce{N_1-N_2, }\mathring{A} & \ce{N_2-N_3, }\mathring{A}  & \ce{N_3-N_4, }\mathring{A}  & \ce{N_4-C_5, }\mathring{A}  & \ce{C_5-N_1, }\mathring{A} \\\hline
\text{sodium tetrazolate}\cdot \ce{H2O} & 1.353 & 1.325 & 1.353 & 1.340 & 1.340 \\
\text{above compound, exp.} & 1.348 & 1.310 & 1.348 & 1.329 & 1.329 \\
\text{$1H$-tetrazole} & 1.353 & 1.292 & 1.366 & 1.315 & 1.348 \\
\text{above compound, exp.} & 1.33 & 1.30 & 1.33 & 1.30 & 1.33 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
The calculations are done at B3LYP/6-31G*. The experimental values are for crystal structures of sodium tetrazolate monohydrate and $1H$-tetrazole, which is the dominated form in solid form (Ref. 2).

References:

Jacqueline F. Satchell and Brian J. Smith, "Calculation of aqueous dissociation constants of 1,2,4-triazole and tetrazole: A comparison of solvation models," Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys. 2002, 4(18), 4314-4318 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1039/B203118C).
V. A. Ostrovskii, G. I. Koldobskii, and R. E. Trifonov, "Chapter 7: Tetrazoles," In Comprehensive Heterocyclic Chemistry III, Volume 6: Other Five-membered Rings with Three or more Heteroatoms, and their Fused Carbocyclic Derivatives; Editors-in-Chief: Alan R. Katritzky, Christopher A. Ramsden, Eric F. V. Scriven, and Richard J. K. Taylor; Elsevier Ltd. (ScienceDirect), 2008, pp 257-423 (ISBN: 978-0-08-044992-0).


thank you, I will look through the paper. I´d appreciate if you could confirm how the distribution of electrons in their orbitals look like. How much in which orbitals?

also why is triazoles pKa of 2.27 given as the single/double protonated form and not the single/deprotonated pair? Is there some convention about that because I find that misleading?

@Lukas4235 Amines in general have acidity of their conjugate acid in pKa tables - neutral are very weakly acidic. Triazoles is borderline case and for tetrazole neutral form's pKa is most important.

It is true that the tetrazole ring is aromatic without being deprotonated, unlike cyclopentadiene. However, the delocalization of the $\pi$ electrons to form this aromatic ring imparts a positive charge to the nitrogen that has a hydrogen atom attached. As is commonplace in such a setting, for example ammonium or pyridinium ions, this charging of the adjoined nitrogen atom makes the hydrogen appreciably acidic.

so electron goes from sp2 into PI orbital and back into some sp2 of nitrogen? How´s the situation in triazole?

also I don´t get why seemingly random whether pka is given as the conjugated acid or of the neutral compound. Triazole eg has pKa of 2.27 which is obviously its conjugated acid.  Is there a consensus I don´t know of?
